# Xampp 3.2.1 error: MySQL shut down unexpectedly

Tags: mysql

I logged into Xampp today and it wouldn't launch MySQL.  It said there was an error and it shut down unexpectedly.  Here are the errors from the error log.  Hoping someone has seen this before, because I have little experience fixing this stuff.

```
2013-11-12 18:21:39 8324 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect key file for table 'user'; try to repair it
2013-11-12 18:27:36 5800 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-11-12 18:27:36 16ac InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-11-12 18:27:36 5800 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-11-12 18:27:36 5800 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-11-12 18:27:36 5800 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-11-12 18:27:36 5800 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-11-12 18:27:36 5800 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2013-11-12 18:27:36 5800 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-11-12 18:27:36 5800 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-11-12 18:27:36 5800 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 0 and 0 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1957328 in the ib_logfiles!
2013-11-12 18:27:36 5800 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2013-11-12 18:27:36 5800 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2013-11-12 18:27:36 5800 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2013-11-12 18:27:36 5800 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2013-11-12 18:27:36 5800 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2013-11-12 18:27:37 5800 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-11-12 18:27:37 5800 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-11-12 18:27:37 5800 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.11 started; log sequence number 1957328
2013-11-12 18:27:37 5800 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2013-11-12 18:27:37 5800 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2013-11-12 18:27:37 5800 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2013-11-12 18:27:37 5800 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2013-11-12 18:27:37 5800 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect key file for table 'user'; try to repair it
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini

open it and add the following line:

```
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

Atleast this was what solved it for me.
I'd backup my .cnf file to be on the safe side.
After adding the single line you should be able to start your mySQL service again.

P.S. I think anything greater than 0 works, since the log error simply states > 0.

Answer (score 0):

**Visit [link](http://krupalpatel92.blogspot.in/2014/12/plugin-federated-is-disabled-xampp.html) for more details**

I have find solution for this error in xampp

1. on start MySQL service we have face some problem
2. Solution for this Error Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled. Just open Task Manager and go in Details tab then find mysqld.exe file stop this task.
3. Let's Re-try  start MySQL Service and see it's working.